# Published variable updates but if/else statement in view does not

Tags: swift, if-statement

I have a published variable in my view model (feedviewmodel) to determine if the view (feedview) should be loading or loaded. The view model sets loading = true so that the progress view shows first and once the data is loaded from Firestore, it should change to false and update the view accordingly (to the else statement). Instead it stays on the default value in the view regardless of whether the published var updates to true or false. Ex. if I set @Published var loading = true, it stays on the loadingview and if i set it equal to false it stays on the loadedview

I have tried moving the dispatchqueue.main.asyncafter in to the firestore request, I've tried removing dispatchqueue altogether and I've tried getting rid of the published var and showing loading as a State var in the view. I have added print statements to see if the bool is actually changing to false and it is.. The view is just not switching to the else statement when the published variable changes. I'm at a loss as to why loading/loaded doesn't work in this view but it does in all my other views.

**FeedViewModel**

```
class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
    @Published var followingPosts = [Post]()
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    @Published var loading = true
    
    let service = FeedService()

    init() {
        if self.followingPosts.isEmpty {
            fetchAllPosts()
        } else {
            fetchFollowingPosts()
        }
    }
    
    func fetchFollowingPosts() {
        guard let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        service.fetchFollowingPosts(forUid: userid) { posts in
            self.followingPosts = posts

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.loading = false
        }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchAllPosts() {
        service.fetchAllPosts { posts in
            self.posts = posts
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            self.loading = false
        }
        }
    }
}
```

**FeedView**

```
struct FeedView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.loading {
            LoadingView
        } else {
            LoadedView
        }
    }
}

extension FeedView {
    
    var LoadedView: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 0) {
            
            Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 54)
            
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                
                PullToRefresh(coordinateSpaceName: "pullToRefresh") {
                    viewModel.fetchFollowingPosts()
                }
                
                if viewModel.followingPosts.isEmpty {
                    Group {
                        Divider()
                        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                            Image("wave")
                                .renderingMode(.template)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                                .foregroundColor(.accentColor).opacity(0.25)

                                Text("Welcome")
                                    .font(Font.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                                
                        }
                        .padding()
                        
                        Divider()
                    }
                    
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 24) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.posts.shuffled().prefix(10), id: \.id) { post in
                            FeedCell(viewModel: FeedCellViewModel(post: post))
                        }
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    LazyVStack (spacing: 24) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.followingPosts, id: \.id) { post in
                            FeedCell(viewModel: FeedCellViewModel(post: post))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: "pullToRefresh")
        }
    }
    
    var LoadingView: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 24) {
            Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 54)
            Spacer()
            ProgressView()
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

**FeedService**

```
struct FeedService {

    func fetchFollowingPosts(forUid uid: String, completion: @escaping([Post]) -> Void) {
        var posts = [Post]()
        
        COLLECTION_FOLLOWING.document(uid).collection("user-following")
            .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
                
                documents.forEach { doc in
                    let userId = doc.documentID
                    
                    COLLECTION_POSTS.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userId)
                    
                        .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
                            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
                            let post = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
                            posts.append(contentsOf: post)
                            
                            completion(posts.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp.dateValue() > $1.timestamp.dateValue()
                            }))
                        }
                }
            }
    }

    func fetchAllPosts(completion: @escaping([Post]) -> Void) {
        COLLECTION_POSTS.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            let posts = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
            completion(posts)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some observations:
it seems to me that in your `FeedViewModel` **init()**, the `if self.followingPosts.isEmpty` is **always** going to be true, because you set `@Published var followingPosts = [Post]()`, and that is an empty array.

 Also, in `func fetchFollowingPosts()` you have `guard let userid = ...` that returns
 without setting `self.loading = false`

Comment: Note, you also have `guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }` in `FeedService` `fetchAllPosts` and `fetchFollowingPosts` that returns without **completion**.
 Deal with these cases and ensure completion is called.

Comment: Thanks for the help! @workingdogsupportUkraine I added print statements for those instances and it seems to be making it through the flows successfully

Comment: did you put a `print(...)` in `FeedViewModel` `fetchAllPosts()` just after `self.loading = false`?

Comment: Yes I added print("is view model loading?  \(self.loading)") and it prints false like it should since I just set it to false... it doesn't update in the view though @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: added my test code to show setting `self.loading = false` works. Maybe you have other code that is re-setting loading to true.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the code I use to test setting `self.loading = false` in the `FeedViewModel` and triggering an update of the view. Works well for me.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        FeedView()
    }
}

struct Post: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct FeedService {
    
    func fetchAllPosts(completion: @escaping([Post]) -> Void) {
        var posts = [Post(name: "name-1"), Post(name: "name-2"), Post(name: "name-3")]
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            completion(posts)
        }
    }
    
}

class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var followingPosts = [Post]()
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    @Published var loading = true
    
    let service = FeedService()
    
    init() {
        fetchAllPosts()
    }
    
    func fetchAllPosts() {
        service.fetchAllPosts { posts in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                self.posts = posts
                self.loading = false
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct FeedView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.loading {
            VStack {
                Text("LoadingView").foregroundColor(.blue)
                ProgressView()
            }
        } else {
            List(viewModel.posts) { post in
                Text("LoadedView \(post.name)").foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```